# Do I really need entire new brake system for all 4

Tags: brakes

I have a 1999 Acura Integra bought from friend in business and new/rebuilt engine was put it, yr car that has been sitting outside not driven for 7 years. I had a semi official mechanic come to look at the car to get it road ready,(flush old gas, oil,coolant etc) One of the things he said needed to be done was to change all 4 brake parts even though pads were replaced 3 months b4 it began sitting undriven. He visual looked at my rims and since he saw rust on the rotor he advised that they all 4 would need to be replaced due to pitting. He suggested I purchase $500 kit from Advanced Auto Parts that contained everything needed to replace all everything for 4 brakes. Could he tell the rotors are pitted without actually taken them off and if I do need new rotors do I need to replace the pads that were 2 months old before the car was parked. I don’t have a lot of $ to get this car on the road and there are additional things besides changing all the fluids he advised since tires have gone mostly flat, although they have good tread and don’t appear dry rotted so I need to spend as least as possible at least right now to get it running,so I am able to get to a new job starting in 2-3 weeks.     Addition: New battery was put in yesterday when person who is helping to get it road ready, he started it up for 2 seconds with old fuel said it was to check to see if car something can’t remember name wasn’t locked up, since new old fuel wasn’t changed could that of now caused additional problems to any part of fuel system. Pls help Ty

Comment: Some photos of the rotors may help.

Comment: Reply to Handy- Will photos of rotors with the tire on car be of use

Comment: If you can see the rotors clearly through the rim then yes, it depends on the rim @ChristinaL. Feel free to post a couple of pictures to see. Also please edit with the make, model and year of the car.

Comment: After even a few months of sitting outside and not being driven a car's brakes may be damaged badly enough to need replacement.  After 7 years?  Well unless the environment was exceptionally dry, you probably have badly rusted rotors and they are unsuitable for driving.